# jsf previous button with immediate=true looses entered data

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2

I have a jsf web application that consists of three pages that collects customer information.

Once a customer completes the first page it is submitted, validated and stored to the managed bean. On the second page the customer completes half of the questions and clicks my previous page button which is a jsf command button with the immediate attribute set to true which skips validation and form submission. The issue I have is that the half answered questions on the second page are now lost so that when the customer clicks next on page one to return to page two the questions they have answered will be empty.

Is there a standard way in JSF to archeive this? I previously used Struts one which handled this behaviour.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

In every page loads, jsf builds the view with current controller values. If you did not save this values to the controller bean, they will simply get lost.

1. to avoid sending the form on your button, simply send the data back to the controller per input component using ajax on the onchange event.

Comment: Is this standard practice? Is seems a bit exhaustive to make an ajax call each time a field changes. I assume you would need to have server side code that could handle each form attribute being passed through.